# MailItem.Reply() with newly created MailItem gives "Could not send mail" Error

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, reply, mailitem

I'm stuck with this. Here is my sample Code.
I want to create a mail item and bind it from database like a mail message.
and then i want to reply it with outlook' s reply pattern. adding from:, to:, that horizontal line, etc.etc. above theoriginal mail.. 
but it' s not working for created mail like "Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem"

MailItem.Reply() is working perfectly when the MailItem is one of the Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection Items
what am i missing here?

thanks..

```
            MailItem oItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem;
            oItem.Body = "...";
            oItem.To = "a@b.c";
            oItem.CC = "d@e.f";
            oItem.Subject = "....";
            MailItem response = oItem.Reply();
```

Error Codes Here:
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in HMOutlookAddIn.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not send mail.

Error Code: -2147352567

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reply to newly created items. The Reply method can be used against recieved messages only.

Instead, you need to use the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779.aspx) method of the MailItem class.

```
    mail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
       as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "A programatically generated e-mail";
    mailRecipients = mail.Recipients;
    mailRecipient = mailRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev");
    mailRecipient.Resolve();
    if (mailRecipient.Resolved)
    {
        mail.Send();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "There is no such record in your address book.");
    }
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)